# HTML5 div, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: css, html

Sorry I'm completely new at this. I'm trying to make a div so I can make a box in the middle of my page that everything will go into, like on this site http://www.jellyneo.net/index.php

My HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSSdoc.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <div id="mainbox">
                <p>text</p>
            </div>
        </center>
        <h1> text </h1>
        <p>text</p>
        <h2> text </h2>
        <p>text</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the CSS I did on it looks like this

```
#mainbox {
    width: 900px
    text-align: left
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
margin:auto;
```

this will align it in the center once it is a fixed width.

```
<body style="margin:0;">
        <div  style="width:900px; margin:auto; border:1px solid #000;"  id="mainbox">
            <p>text</p>
     <h1> text </h1>

    <p>text</p>
     <h2> text </h2>

    <p>text</p>
        </div>

</body>
```

I added a border for clarity.

So your body should have

```
body{
margin:0;
}
```

And your box area should have

```
#mainbox{
width:900px; 
margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `<center>` tags in your HTML code; the CSS will help center things for you.  Within your CSSdoc.css file, simply adjust to the following...

```css
#mainbox {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto; /*the 0 here represents the top and bottom margin spacing. it's good to have and control in many cases.*/
    width: 900px;
    border: solid 2px #000; /*this is optional, more for debugging purposes to see your 900px scaled box*/
}
```